# Uploading audio files to Firebase using SwiftUI and AVFoundation

Tags: firebase, swiftui, avfoundation, firebase-storage, avkit

I want to upload audio files to Firebase Storage and then fetch them to play. I try to store the path of the in a global variable:

```
var fileURL: URL?
```

Currently I have the following code the record the audio using AVFoundation:

```
func startRecording() {
            let recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed to set up recording session")
        }
        
        let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        
        let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(Date().toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM-YY_'at'_HH:mm:ss")).m4a")
        
        self.fileURL = audioFilename
        
        let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]
        
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.record()
            
            recording = true
            
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not start recording with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

After this I want to to stop the recording but also upload to file to Firebase. Currently, I have this piece of code which I have written referring to the Firebase documentation based on uploading files form a local reference point. I am not sure how to access to the data of the audio file or what is a good way to upload it directly to Firebase Storage. Here is the full ViewModel code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Firebase

class VoiceViewModel : NSObject ,ObservableObject {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        fetchRecordings()
    }
    
    
    var fileURL: URL?
    
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<VoiceViewModel, Never>()
    
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    
    var recordings = [Recording]()
    
    
    
    @Published var recording = false {
            didSet {
                objectWillChange.send(self)
            }
        }
    
    func startRecording() {
            let recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed to set up recording session")
        }
        
        let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        
        let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(Date().toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM-YY_'at'_HH:mm:ss")).m4a")
        
        self.fileURL = audioFilename
        
        let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]
        
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.record()
            
            recording = true
            
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not start recording with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func stopRecording() {
        audioRecorder.stop()
        recording = false
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        let localfile = self.fileURL ?? URL(string: "")
        
        let fileRef = storageRef.child("images/try.m4a")
        
        print(self.fileURL?.absoluteURL)
        let uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(from: localfile!, metadata: nil) { metaData, err in
            guard let metadata = metaData else { return }
            
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            fileRef.downloadURL { (url, err) in
                guard let downloadUrl = url else { return }
                
                print(downloadUrl)
            }
            
        }
        
        
        fetchRecordings()
    }
       
    
    func fetchRecordings() {
            recordings.removeAll()
            
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            for audio in directoryContents {
                let recording = Recording(fileURL: audio, createdAt: getCreationDate(for: audio))
                recordings.append(recording)
                
                recordings.sort(by: { $0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .orderedAscending})
                objectWillChange.send(self)
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: You seem to have code written already for uploading the file. Can you clarify where the problem is or where you're getting result that you don't expect? Also, side note, you don't need the `didSet { objectWillChange.send(self) } ` on your `@Published` property -- that was only necessary in the beta period of SwiftUI 1.0.

Comment: When I call the startRecording function, I do not get any errors. When I call the stopRecording function I get the following error: AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id. I am not sure where the problem is. When I print out the self.fileURL function, I get back the local path.

Comment: Did you search SO for this? This question and answers seems to deal with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360765/swift-5-1-error-plugin-addinstanceforfactory-no-factory-registered-for-id-c

Comment: Yes, this is about the AVPlayer. I get the error when I try to upload the file to Firebase.

Comment: The 'audioRecorder.stop()' function comes from the 'AVAudioRecorder' class. And the audio fille gets saved in the device without any problems. However, the file does not get uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Comment: You're returning before printing the error in the event that `metaData` is `nil` -- are you sure there's no error?

Comment: Yeah, weirdly there is no error. So do you think the Firebase function is allowed to reach the audio file in the device?

Comment: Yes -- if you can write it, you can read it.

Comment: I get these in my log during the process of recording an audio in the app: 'App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.'  ' AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID'. I print out the 'self.fuleURL' and get this: file:///Users/my-user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C59FE998-3753-49B1-978C-87C8FEB18CCA/data/Containers/Data/Application/EF84F8A5-E9FB-45B0-944B-F99B761AB285/Documents/08-05-21_at_10:47:29.m4a and lastly this: 'nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed'

Comment: Monitor the upload and see what happens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress

Comment: I did an in turned the .unauthorized case with description: // User doesn't have permission to access file

Comment: However, before that it also printed out the 'percentComplete' too. Here is the exact log: 0.22237496462216472
0.22237496462216472
unauth

Comment: It was about the Firebase Storage rules. Thanks mate