# AVPlayerViewController gives error AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000365d520>

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm learning to build tvOs Applications but unfortunately, my fullscreen player is not working. I'm building a simple app that launches a full-screen video when the user taps a button. But I'm getting this error.

**Error**

```
2021-09-29 01:27:20.962684+0530 CustomViewFun[4432:181636] [plugin] 
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000365d520> F8BB1C28- 
BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2021-09-29 01:27:23.009069+0530 CustomViewFun[4432:181779] [] 
nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed: 
dlopen(/usr/lib/libquic.dylib, 0x0005): tried: 
'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomViewFun- 
ajfybetvgzvjdrepropppgxffjvs/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/libquic.dylib' (no 
such file), '

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection/libquic.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libquic.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libquic.dylib' (no such file)
2021-09-29 01:27:27.600430+0530 CustomViewFun[4432:181885] [aqme]        MEMixerChannel.cpp:868   MEMixerChannel::EnableProcessor: failed to open processor type 0x705f6571
```

**This is my code**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer : AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
        let movieURL:URL? = URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
    
        //Optional Binding
        if let url = movieURL {
            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = avPlayer
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Press To play video
        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) {
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to resolve it by myself by changing NSURL to URL because AVplayer requires URL instead of NSURL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 5.1 Error: \[plugin\] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360765/swift-5-1-error-plugin-addinstanceforfactory-no-factory-registered-for-id-c)

Comment: I have tried this solution before. It didn't worked for me.