# `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` causes console error `[plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000b446c0>`

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, runtime-error, avaudiosession

Whenever I write the code `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` in my SwiftUI app, I get the following error message printed in the console: `[plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000068f420> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46`.

Is there anything I can do to stop this message from getting printed?

I'm running Xcode version 13.3.1, deployment target iOS 15, on simulator running iOS 15.4

Answer (score 0):

iOS simulators sometimes have such issues, however this console error might not be present when testen on real device. Try adding `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` as a global variable just after importing `AVFoundation`. I am basically suggesting the same solution as on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360765/swift-5-1-error-plugin-addinstanceforfactory-no-factory-registered-for-id-c)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately that solution doesn't work for me. But you're right that when running my app on a real device the console error is not present.