# Swift 5.7 Error: [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id

Tags: swift, avfoundation, instance, avaudioplayer

Everything is work fine, but why I get this error.

[image: Xcode Debug Area]

This is all my code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound()
    }
    
    func playSound() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
    }

}
```

The results are the same as I expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 5.1 Error: \[plugin\] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360765/swift-5-1-error-plugin-addinstanceforfactory-no-factory-registered-for-id-c)

Comment: I already tried this, the error remains.

Comment: Have you read the second answer: `I believe the error message is a warning for simulators hence it is not important.`? Have you tested this on a real device?  Does the warning persist?

Comment: Thank you, @burnsi! I tried on a real device, there is no such error.