# How can I remove swift process message

Tags: swift, stdout, child-process, stderr, stdio

Whenever I run the following code, a sound is played perfectly fine but it always prints something to the console.
code:

```swift
let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let task = Process()
        
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments  = ["afplay", path]
        
let _ = try? task.run()
        
task.waitUntilExit()
```

console message:

```
2023-05-07 01:18:05.779125+0200 afplay[7755:301446] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000020c1c0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2023-05-07 01:18:05.799089+0200 afplay[7755:301446] [aqme]        MEMixerChannel.cpp:1636  client <AudioQueueObject@0x10100f200; [0]; play> got error 2003332927 while sending format information
2023-05-07 01:18:06.554636+0200 afplay[7755:301448] [aqme]        MEMixerChannel.cpp:1636  client <AudioQueueObject@0x10100f200; [0]; play> got error 2003332927 while sending format information
You are in First Layer spawn
```

I've tried clearing the terminal by running a different process with launchPath `/usr/bin/clear` but it still doesn't work

Comment: I think this problem might be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360765/swift-5-1-error-plugin-addinstanceforfactory-no-factory-registered-for-id-c?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting [`task.standardOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1407627-standardoutput) and [`task.standardError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1414916-standarderror) to `nil` before calling `task.run()`, I think will cause anything the subprocess outputs to stdout and stderr to be ignored.

Comment: `task.standardError` solves it thanks.